# Why absolute maximum is not local maximum when it occurs at an endpoint?

Tags: calculus

"Absolute maximum is not local maximum when it occurs at an endpoint",I saw definition of local maximum in my textbook have not such a statement.But the example add it. My textbook is Calculus(James Stewart)(eighth edition).

And definition is as shown below.

The number $f(c)$ is $a$.

local maximum value of $f$ if $f(c) \geqslant f(x)$ when x is near c.

local minimum value of $f$ if $f(c) \leqslant f(x)$ when x is near c.
[image]

And the example is shown below.
[image]

So why absolute maximum is not local maximum when it occurs at an endpoint?

Comment: I don't see anything in that definition which precludes a local extremum from occurring at an endpoint.  A more complete reference would help, as well as the definition of an "absolute maximum" according to your text.

Comment: If the domain is $[a,b]$, then the only values of $x$ to consider are those in the closed interval. So if $f(a)\ge f(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$, then $f(a)$ is the absolute maximum value. And it certainly is a local maximum. Reread my first sentence.

Comment: You can think of a maximum or a minimum as a point where the value of the function at any nearby points to either side or higher (For minimum) or lower (for maximum) than the point in question. This includes points where nearby points to one side or the other do not exist, which is the case at a boundary. Further, continuous functions are typically monotonic in the neighbor hood of a boundary. A local maximum happens when it isn't the highest possible value, just the highest of nearby allowed values.

Comment: Again, what book is this?

Comment: The textbook is Calculus(James Stewart)(eighth edition)

Comment: I would suggest that you find a better book.  The definition of a local extremum that is given above is quite vague (what is the meaning of "near"?  this should be made more precise), and the example is contrary to every other text I have on hand (even Thomas' Calculus, 14E, would say that the function pictured above has local maxima at $-1$ and $4$).

Comment: Thank you very much！I will try so.Thanks for your answer again.

Comment: May I ask you for a calculus textbook that suits beginner？

Comment: I recommended *Thomas' Calculus*, above, which is at a similar level to Stewart.  Broussard has a book that is supposed to be reasonable (I am not personally familiar with it).  But, honestly, most "introductory" calculus texts are not that great---there is usually a lot of hand waving and ellision.